# Differences between creating and writing html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanna know what is different between:

```
// Way 1
var html = '<div id="4" class="selected">
               <span id="span2">Content</span>
            </div>';


// Way 2 
var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 4).addClass('selected');
var span = $('<span>').attr('id', 'span2').text('Content');
div.append(span);
var html = div;
```

**Way 1** is simple.

**Way 2** looks good in this case, but when nested elements are more, may be difficult to write and read.

Is there anything special in **Way 2** ?

Comment: note that Way 1 doesn't create an element instance in the memory while Way 2 does.

Comment: Performancewise way1 is better but codingwise way2 is suggested. Also way2 may be coz its jquery and will be supported in all browsers..

Comment: I think looping wiser 1 one is better

Comment: "Way 2" gives you jQuery objects which have all the jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Way2 you can edit each object easily. Like add text, delete tag or attribute.
But in Way1 when nested elements are more, you cant find each area you want easily , and if you want to edit html, you will spend more time to look for your tag which you want to edit. 
So I think Way2 is better than Way1 when nested elements are more

Answer (score 0):

Way2 is for dynamic purpose only.